# Is this an efficient way of rendering tiles with OpenGL?

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl, opengl-compat

This is the routine I use for rendering the tiles

```java
    private static void renderTile(int x1, int y1, int size) {
        glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);

        double halfSize = size/2;

        glVertex2d(x1 + halfSize, y1 + halfSize);
        glVertex2d(x1 + halfSize, y1 - halfSize);
        glVertex2d(x1 - halfSize, y1 - halfSize);

        glVertex2d(x1 - halfSize, y1 - halfSize);
        glVertex2d(x1 - halfSize, y1 + halfSize);
        glVertex2d(x1 + halfSize, y1 + halfSize);
        glEnd();
    }
```

Now, the routine works, but, it looks a bit messy. Is there a better way to do this with Java OpenGL + LWJGL?

Comment: You're using the opengl 1 api. Using a modern opengl api is better.

Comment: What's the exact reason for using tiles? Maybe you don't need tiles all along and achieve the same result by rendering just a single quad and an appropriate fragment shader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code in old GL has major problems:

- computing the coordinates inside `glBegin/glEnd`
- mixing `double` and `int` forcing costly conversion between types
- not using vectors
- expensive primitive
- using `double`

Much faster would be to use `glVertex2dv` and precompute the coordinates once into some table (sadly your current api does not support static table that would require change in your app architecture). From that its a simple small leap into VBO usage btw. Also `doubles` are usually wasted in old GL as the interpolators are 32bit anyways (even on new HW). So to optimize I would convert your code to something like this (sorry not a JAVA coder I code in C++ so it might be syntacticaly incorrect):

```
private static void renderTile(float x, float y, float size) 
    {
    const float  a = 0.5*size;
    const float p[4*2]= 
        {
        x-a,y-a,
        x+a,y-a,
        x+a,y+a,
        x-a,y+a,
        };

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glVertex2fv(p); p+=2;
    glVertex2fv(p); p+=2;
    glVertex2fv(p); p+=2;
    glVertex2fv(p); p+=2;
    glEnd();
    }
```

However if you want true power then use VBO. See

- [complete GL+GLSL+VAO/VBO C++ example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31913542/2521214).

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not efficient. You should use display lists or even better - vertex buffer object (VBO).

Comment: `DisplayLists` usually slows things down on current HW... they where a thing 20 years ago but even then only for some gfx cards.